# i am facing this problem in my ubuntu from last hour. what i did not remember

Tags: boot

```
error found when loading /home/ganesh/.profile: 
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): no such file or directory
As a result the session will not be configured correctly. 
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

[image: error-image]

Comment: so how about removing that line?

Comment: which line brother?

Comment: `exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass)` in .profile It was probably manually added where ssh askpass was later removed.

Comment: bro i cant understand your anything. is any chance to solve or remove this problem. please reply with more explanation. pardon me for my behaviour that asking you for more explantion. because i'm newbie in this linux ubuntu and currently started learning python. so just for that please help me. and forgive me if you can.
please dm me in tg if you can: @thakareganesh

Comment: edit `/home/ganesh/.profile`  with vi or gedit or whatever editor you fancy find the  the line that refer to "exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass)" delete it and save the file.